# What does -d stand for in curl request?

Tags: http, curl

I am trying to send this HTTP request in Postman application:

```
curl -v https://api.someurl.com/z1/lists \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: authorization" \
  -d '{ "list_id": "DXVBDAD" }'
```

Any body knows what -d stands for? and where should I put it in Postman?

Comment: -d is for data, look to the manual.

Comment: use `man curl` cmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) says this:

> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server[...]

So this will be the body of your POST request. In Postman you have to put it into the 'body' field. There select 'raw' and then select 'application/json'.
Because that's the Content-Type of your request, specified with -H.

[image: This is what your Postman should look like]

Answer (score 3):

The `-d` or `--data` option makes the `curl` command send data in  **POST** request to the server. This option makes the `curl` command pass data to the server using **content-type** (**JSON** in your case) just as the browser does when a user submits a form.